# How do i set the dimensions of an image before setting as an icon for a label

Tags: codenameone

I would like to know create an image collection without using an ImageView. I want to set the image dimensions and then add the image to a label.

final ScaleImageLabel path = new ScaleImageLabel();

```
    final ScaleImageLabel path1 = new ScaleImageLabel();
           final ScaleImageLabel path2 = new ScaleImageLabel();
    try {
        if (landingInfo.getImagePath()!= null) {
            Image backgroundImage = Image.createImage(landingInfo.getImagePath());
            backgroundImage.scaled(100, 100);
            path.setIcon(backgroundImage);
            path.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED);
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem or UI you're trying to accomplish. You can set the dimension of the image either via scaling or by defining the preferred size of the `ScaledImageLabel`. This should be pretty easy. What did you try?

Comment: I want to create an Image Gallery or Collection with a grid of images. Just like the android OS image gallery

Comment: I suggest using scale to fill not "scaled". Then just place the labels in a grid layout. What's the problem?